# rendering SVG from segments using networkx is not similar to actual SVG image

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, networkx

I'm trying to render a SVG, it's content is pretty simple:

```
        <svg width="3000" height="3000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M217 279H473Q441 364 409.5 443.0Q378 522 345 607ZM-2 4V66H63L325 747H415L677 66H750V4H474V66H553L495 217H194L137 66H215V4Z" fill="red" />
        </svg>
```

It's an alphabet (A), flipped vertically, that's all. Now I'm read this file using `xml.etree.ElementTree`. Then parsing path with `svg.path.parse_path`.

I've only one path here: `M217 279H473Q441 364 409.5 443.0Q378 522 345 607ZM-2 4V66H63L325 747H415L677 66H750V4H474V66H553L495 217H194L137 66H215V4Z`. If I translate it into 2D coordinate system, it looks something like this:

```
Path(Move(to=(217+279j)), Line(start=(217+279j), end=(473+279j)), QuadraticBezier(start=(473+279j), control=(441+364j), end=(409.5+443j), smooth=False), QuadraticBezier(start=(409.5+443j), control=(378+522j), end=(345+607j), smooth=False), Close(start=(345+607j), end=(217+279j)), Move(to=(-2+4j)), Line(start=(-2+4j), end=(-2+66j)), Line(start=(-2+66j), end=(63+66j)), Line(start=(63+66j), end=(325+747j)), Line(start=(325+747j), end=(415+747j)), Line(start=(415+747j), end=(677+66j)), Line(start=(677+66j), end=(750+66j)), Line(start=(750+66j), end=(750+4j)), Line(start=(750+4j), end=(474+4j)), Line(start=(474+4j), end=(474+66j)), Line(start=(474+66j), end=(553+66j)), Line(start=(553+66j), end=(495+217j)), Line(start=(495+217j), end=(194+217j)), Line(start=(194+217j), end=(137+66j)), Line(start=(137+66j), end=(215+66j)), Line(start=(215+66j), end=(215+4j)), Close(start=(215+4j), end=(-2+4j)))
```

Then I try to parse all nodes and edges from this data:

```
node: (-2.0, 4.0)
node: (-2.0, 66.0)
node: (63.0, 66.0)
node: (137.0, 66.0)
node: (194.0, 217.0)
node: (215.0, 4.0)
node: (215.0, 66.0)
node: (217.0, 279.0)
node: (325.0, 747.0)
node: (345.0, 607.0)
node: (409.5, 443.0)
node: (415.0, 747.0)
node: (473.0, 279.0)
node: (474.0, 4.0)
node: (474.0, 66.0)
node: (495.0, 217.0)
node: (553.0, 66.0)
node: (677.0, 66.0)
node: (750.0, 4.0)
node: (750.0, 66.0)
edge: (0, 0)
edge: (0, 1)
edge: (1, 2)
edge: (2, 3)
edge: (3, 0)
edge: (4, 4)
edge: (4, 5)
edge: (5, 6)
edge: (6, 7)
edge: (7, 8)
edge: (8, 9)
edge: (9, 10)
edge: (10, 11)
edge: (11, 12)
edge: (12, 13)
edge: (13, 14)
edge: (14, 15)
edge: (15, 16)
edge: (16, 17)
edge: (17, 18)
edge: (18, 19)
edge: (19, 4)
```

Then I'm using `networkx` and `matplotlib` together to visualize it:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a new graph
G = nx.Graph()

# Add nodes to the graph
for node in nodes:
    G.add_node(node)
    print("node:",node)

# Add edges to the graph
for edge in edges:
    e1, e2 = edge
    G.add_edge(*(nodes[e1],nodes[e2]))
    print("edge:",edge)

# Create a plot
pos = {node: (node[0], node[1]) for node in nodes}
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color='lightblue', edge_color='gray', node_size=1000)
nx.draw(G) #, pos, with_labels=True, node_color='lightblue', edge_color='gray', node_size=1000)
# plt.title(cha)
plt.show()
```

But what is being represented to me is quite different than expected:

[image: rendering svg with networkx]

Actual image:

[image: actual image of inverted A]

I've always used some graphics library to render these stuff. This is my first time processing SVG files directly for rendering. Am I missing any steps? How can I resolve this issue?

Although it looks like an 'A', but when I try with other alphabets, it's nowhere close to that alphabet.